# Using awk and grep to add up

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

If I had a file that looks like this:

```
23.00   33.44 abcd 44.44  abcd12345abcd
33.00   22.22 qt   44.00  zlkm12345ksda
```

...and I wanted to add up the first column whenever I encounter 12345 in the middle of the pattern in the fifth column, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
awk '$5 ~ /12345/ { TOT = TOT + $1 } END { print TOT + 0 }' yourFile.txt
```

(Not at a computer, so my syntax might be a bit off.)

The first bit selects the lines you want and updates the total while the END bit just prints what's accumulated.

No grep needed (for almost all intents and purposes, awk is just as good if not better), and the search is limited to just the column you want searched.

Comment: You might want to add `yourFile.txt` or somesuch at the end. You might want to print `TOT + 0` at the end, so that if no lines match and TOT is an empty string, the program will print `0` instead of nothing.

Comment: How do I make it open a file? I know this is very basic

Comment: @Identical: awk by default assumes that the first argument is the program to run and everything else are the input file(s).  You can alter that behavior a bit with flags, but that's the default.  Note that my answer has the whole program in single quotes--the entire thing is the first argument.

Comment: Don't use all-upper-case variable names to avoid clashes with builtin variable names, and you can use `tot+=1` instead of `tot=tot+1`.